# e.stopPropagation works but presents error in console

Tags: jquery, function, events, stoppropagation

Here's my code, it works but the console gives me this message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object 2 has no method 'stopPropagation'

This is my code:

```
$(".addtag").click(function () {
    var current_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    $('div .tag').each(function (e) {
        var this_tag_id = $(this).attr("id").replace("tag", "");
        if (this_tag_id == current_id) {
            alert("You can't tag an item twice");
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
$("body").css("color","red"); <--- if (this_tag_id == current_id) I want to prevent this from executing.
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `e` is not an event object in this case, actually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared `e` as the argument to `each`, not as the argument to your event handler, and so `e` is a DOM element, not an event object, and doesn't have `stopPropagation`. Move the `e` argument out of the `each` function and into the function handling the click.

```
$(".addtag").click(function(e) {
// Here --------------------^
var current_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
  $('div .tag').each(function(){
// Not here ------------------^
      var this_tag_id = $(this).attr("id").replace("tag","");
      if (this_tag_id == current_id) {alert("You can't tag an item twice"); e.stopPropagation();}
  });
}
```

---

Re your comment below:

```
$(".addtag").click(function (e) {
    var current_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    $('div .tag').each(function () {
        var this_tag_id = $(this).attr("id").replace("tag", "");
        if (this_tag_id == current_id) {
            alert("You can't tag an item twice");
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
    $("body").css("color", "red"); // <-- I want to prevent this from executing if this_tag_id == current_id.
});
```

Set a flag in your `each`, and check it after:

```
$(".addtag").click(function (e) {
    var current_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    var iscurrent = false;       // <=== Flag
    $('div .tag').each(function () {
        var this_tag_id = $(this).attr("id").replace("tag", "");
        if (this_tag_id == current_id) {
            iscurrent = true;    // <=== Set
            e.stopPropagation(); // <=== Put this above alert
            alert("You can't tag an item twice");
        }
    });
    if (!iscurrent) {            // <=== Add check
        $("body").css("color", "red");
    }
});
```

Comment: While the error isn't showing, its still executing the code, but I want it to break out of the function and the event.

Comment: @NirTzezana: `alert` messes with a lot of things, I wouldn't use it or I'd use it via `setTimeout` so it doesn't interfere with the event handling (e.g.: `setTimeout(function() { alert("..."); }, 0);`. If you want to prevent the default action, you'll need `e.preventDefault` rather than (or in addition to) `e.stopPropagation`.

Comment: Updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: @NirTzezana: That's a different question...but I've answered it above. I don't *know* that you have to move the `stopPropagation` above the `alert`, but I would. The main bit there, though, is the flag.

Comment: @NirTzezana: It's close, though not quite the same. In just about any programming language, `x == true` or `x == false` is entirely pointless -- just test `x` directly. In JavaScript, `x` doesn't even have to be boolean -- you can test any value. All values are either truthy or falsey. The falsey values are `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`. Everything else is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your meaning:

```
$(".addtag").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var current_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    $('div .tag').each(function (e) {
        var this_tag_id = $(this).attr("id").replace("tag", "");
        if (this_tag_id == current_id) {
            alert("You can't tag an item twice");
            return false;// will break the each loop here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @NirTzezana: It stops the loop, but doesn't prevent the code you didn't show originally in the question from running.

Comment: @NirTzezana so  T.J. Crowder updated answer will work in this case